# Why's that? Can't convert into String: I do have a to_s method!

Tags: ruby

I don't understand why the following raises an exception:

```
class X
  def to_s
    "x"
  end
end

s = ""
s << X.new
# --> TypeError: can't convert X into String
```

After all 'to_s' is supposed to convert X into a String.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short conversions aren't called automatically by the Ruby core; that's what the long conversions are for. The long conversions are intended for things that are very much like the conversion target already, as opposed to things that simply have a *representation* of the target type.

Use: `to_str`

That is, if you add `def to_str; "x"; end` to your class the `<<` expression will work with an automatic conversion.

Answer (score 6):

> After all `to_s` is supposed to convert `X` into a `String`.

No, it's not. It is supposed to *represent* it as a `String`. `to_str` is supposed to *convert* it.

Answer (score -1):

There is not any automatic cast in Ruby ; you have to call explicitly your method to_s:

```
s << X.new.to_s
```

Comment: As it urns out there is: I just should have used to_str above.

Comment: @radiospiel is correct. There are several automatic conversions. For one thing,  the Ruby core applies the long conversions (to_int, to_str, ...) almost everywhere. It's just that the short converters are intended for explicit use, so they are not "automatic".